# Just installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my Acer Aspire 5740G laptop, it constantly shuts down itself due temperature, how to diagnostique?

Tags: 12.04, kernel, shutdown, acer

I don't know what causes it since I just installed Ubuntu on my laptop.

Here is the issue. Ubuntu boots normally, so I can use firefox and such. However, after 2-3 minutes, laptop shuts down. (I see Ubuntu logo for 1 second before shutdown.)

Fans are usually working loud.

GPU drivers (5470) doesn't seem to be installed.

Anyone knows what can be the issue?

Ps. Previously, I used Windows 7 and it didn't create any issues.

Comment: Does the laptop feels hot? This sounds like a temperature issue for all sides.

Comment: Yes, incredibly hot. I can't even touch the bottom of it, and sensors are mostly around 85-90 degree.

Comment: I recommend you to read [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/85830/41104) and follow the advise to diagnostic and possibly fix the problem. If you have done everything and your system still spike, then edit your question including everything you tried and the results and leave me a comment to keep me updated.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are 90% of the way there, having actually checked the GPU drivers.

There are several versions of the Acer Aspire 5740, some with Intel Mobile graphics and the others with ATI Radeon Mobility graphics. There are reports from some ATI users that they need to install the proprietary FGLRX drivers (via System Settings, Additional Drivers) for system temperatures to be more normal.

Comment: I guess I've solved the issue like this. Right now fans are normal and temps are around 60 degree on basic usage. I'm using Radeon 5470M as a GPU.